# Why does the console.log print the state for a second time after i click the button even though the value of the state doesn't change?

Tags: reactjs

**First case**

It seems that the app component renders for a second time when I click on the button for a second time although it shouldn't because the state doesn't change if it is the same value, right?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [someState, changeSomeState] = useState(null);
  console.log(someState);
  console.log('App component rendered');

  return (
    <>
      
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          changeSomeState(6666);
        }}
      >
        Button in App
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Second case**

It seems that the app component renders for a second time, but the test component that is being rendered inside the app is only being rendered once after the button was clicked, again why?

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Test from "./Test";
const App = () => {
  const [someState, changeSomeState] = useState(null);
  console.log(someState);

  return (
    <>
      <Test />;
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          changeSomeState(6666);
        }}
      >
        Button in App
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Here we have the component named `Test` with a `console.log` that runs on every re-render :

```
import React from "react";

const Test = () => {
  console.log("Test component rendered");

  return <div>Test</div>;
};

export default Test;
```

React is weird.

Answer (score 0):

In React, components can re-render even if the `state` value `does not` change, due to updates to props or context.

This is why you might see a component render `twice` when clicking a button.

Using `React.memo` can help prevent `unnecessary re-renders` for functional components that do not expect updates to their props or context.

```
import React, { useState, memo } from "react";

const Test = memo(() => {
  console.log("Test component rendered");

  return <div>Test</div>;
});

const App = () => {
  const [someState, changeSomeState] = useState(null);
  console.log(someState);

  return (
    <>
      <Test />;
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          changeSomeState(6666);
        }}
      >
        Button in App
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Now, the Test component will only re-render when its props or context are updated, not on every state update in the App component.